# Is it possible to make m3u8 file smaller by removing the base URL parts of all ts file URL in m3u8

Tags: http-live-streaming, m3u8, m3u

1). My .m3u8 files and all .ts files are all located at a website like http://m3u8.abc.com/xxx.m3u8(.ts).

2). In m3u8 file, every #EXTINF parts points to a URL such as:

```
#EXTINF:3.436767,  
http://m3u8.ffmlive.com/47AE361A16FF0BA311E272CA925AEB4004751D6C0000.ts
#EXTINF:2.268933,
http://m3u8.ffmlive.com/47AE361A16FF0BA311E272CA925AEB4004751D6C0001.ts
#EXTINF:1.968633,
http://m3u8.ffmlive.com/47AE361A16FF0BA311E272CA925AEB4004751D6C0002.ts
#EXTINF:1.034367,
http://m3u8.ffmlive.com/47AE361A16FF0BA311E272CA925AEB4004751D6C0003.ts
...
```

3). There are hundreds of .ts files in each m3u8 file.

**My question is**: Does m3u8 file standard supports to set a base URL, and make all segment parts use relative URIs. so it helps to make m3u8 file smaller and easier to load. such as

```
#EXT-X-BASE-URL: http://m3u8.ffmlive.com
#EXTINF:3.436767,  
/47AE361A16FF0BA311E272CA925AEB4004751D6C0000.ts
#EXTINF:2.268933,
/47AE361A16FF0BA311E272CA925AEB4004751D6C0001.ts
#EXTINF:1.968633,
/47AE361A16FF0BA311E272CA925AEB4004751D6C0002.ts
#EXTINF:1.034367,
/47AE361A16FF0BA311E272CA925AEB4004751D6C0003.ts
...
```

If it does, how to do with it?

Answer (score 4):

It supports realitive URLs, just like HTML. But the base is the manifest URL, and there is not a way to override that.

Comment: Many thanks for this - could you show how to specify the base via the manifest URL?

Comment: You don’t specify it. The base is the url that the manifest is hosted at.